# perl module not found: still missing a file Telnet.pm after adding it to the path

Tags: perl, path, telnet

I'm getting the following error while trying to conect via

```
use FileHandle;
use IPC::Open2;

$p=open2(\*R,\*W,"cr");

$username = "m";  # your login HERE
$passwd = "s"; # your PASSWORD here
use Net::Telnet ();
$telnet = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 4000,
                         Prompt => '/c% /',
                         Port => 2000 );
```

I have created the directory `Net/Telnet.pm` in my `@INC` but it didn't helped.
What should I fix yet ?

```
$ perl tm8.pl
Can't locate Net/Telnet.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::Telnet module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.30 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30 /usr/lib/perl5/5.30/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.30) at tm8.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tm8.pl line 8.
```

Comment: It doesn't look for a directory named `Net/Telnet.pm`, but a file. And not any file named that but the module in question. Do as instructed and install the module: `cpan Net::Telnet`

Comment: Try installing Net::Telnet from cpan.  "perl -MCPAN -e shell <enter>
install Net::Telnet". Also, add 'use strict;' and 'use warnings;' to the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you already try install the Net::Telnet with `cpanm Net::Telnet` or

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Net::Telnet
```

I suggest for you try install the Net::Telnet with `sudo` command:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Net::Telnet
```

Comment: From looking at the paths in @INC I assumed this was cygwin on Windows. Cygwin doesn't have 'sudo'. Why do you suggest the use of 'sudo'?